# Organise AWS CodeCommit repositories in groups/projects

Tags: aws-codecommit

I am just starting with AWS CodeCommit and wonder, how can I organize Repos into projects/groups.

Coming from GitLab, I can create a "Group" and within this group, I create my repos.

For example, I have a project "MyApp" with a server, web-client, ios-client, android-client repo, I have 4 repos in the group "MyApp". You get the idea :-)

I cannot find anything like that in CodeCommit.

I did find "Tags". Is that the Amazons solution for groups? 
Or am I missing something?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature is, regrettably, not supported in CodeCommit as of today. CodeCommit provides ways of sharing repositories with different entities and grant them access [1][2][3], but there is no feature to group different repositories together on the CodeCommit console in a visual way that is comparable to what GitLab Groups does today.

References:

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-share-repository.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/auth-and-access-control.html
[3] https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/refining-access-to-branches-in-aws-codecommit/

Comment: Just curious as it's been 4 years: anyone know if this feature is on codecommit's radar?